How do I combine many materials into only one for a mesh?
I just modeled a character head that I want to export but I need there to be only one material. However I have 11 materials. I also texture painted on some of them. I’m not sure how to join them together into one without them breaking. I did not use any images for materials, only colors and painted on textures.
I'm exporting this model to Roblox Studio.

Is it possible for you to use images in the system you are exporting to? Is it possible to break your single head into many different models? What are you exporting to, and what are the limitations there? Many things are possible in Blender, but if they're not supported in the system you're going to, it does not matter.

I'm not sure what kind of export you want to do that you can only use one material... of course you could put all shaders in a single material and then mix them in a way that they all get just the parts of the shader they need. But I will not recommend anything unless I know what other restrictions there might be to export if for example only one material is allowed. What about thinks like textures? UV maps? Vertex groups?

Here are the limitations for Roblox Studio. Looks like a single PBR with textures is supported (well, four materials are possible, but only as part of a material variant that applies exactly one at a time). See also the mesh export settings and character limitations.

Thank you Phrogz. I will try to narrow it down to four materials and import it. I tried to use shaders to combine the materials but when I did, a texture drawing I made went to a place where it shouldn’t be. How do I stop that?

@LiniMac You should make it a single material, using maps with UVs to control what appearance is applied to different places. Perhaps Gordon will give you more details.

I was going to smart UV project but that got rid of the drawing textures before.

At a glance, it should be just a matter of baking the relevant data into image textures. This website already have quite a few topics about baking textures from multiple materials. So I recommend you to look up the different topics, see how it works without breaking your existing materials and try on your side. If you have specific issues that aren't answered already, please come back here and [edit] your question to add the updated detail and it will queue up your topic for reopening.
